# Reading Xml Documentation generated by visual studio from c#

Tags: c#, xml-comments

We need to parse out and display class documentation for certain classes from Xml documents produced during our build process (for our .Net assemblies) for certain web-service data contracts on a website?

We can use Linq2Xml and do it the hard way but I was wondering if someone's already done this?

Comment: You might want to look into whether you could hook into Sandcastle.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [NDoc3](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndoc3/index.php?title=About)?